# Storing and pasting an entire range

Tags: vba, excel

All, I'm trying to do a quasi-montecarlo analysis, and have had success storing values from single cells into an array during every draw, and then pasting later.  When I'm trying to store an entire row into an array, though, the script doesn't seem to work.  Hoping someone can shed some insight, thank you for your help!  This issue is somewhere in the `curvearray`, which is copying 10 cells in the same row on each draw.

```
Dim randa As Double
Dim stdeva As Double

Dim looprun As Double
Dim arrayone() As Variant
Dim arraytwo() As Variant
Dim curvearray() As Variant

ReDim arrayone(1 To 1)
ReDim arraytwo(1 To 1)
ReDim curvarray(1 To 10)

stdeva = 1
a = Range("baseline").Value

For looprun = 1 To 100

randa = Rnd

Range("baseline").Value = WorksheetFunction.NormInv(randa, a, stdeva)
Application.Calculate

arrayone(UBound(arrayone)) = Range("net").Value
ReDim Preserve arrayone(1 To UBound(arrayone) + 1)

arraytwo(UBound(arraytwo)) = Range("multi").Value
ReDim Preserve arraytwo(1 To UBound(arraytwo) + 1)

curvearray(UBound(curvearray)) = Range("curve").Value
ReDim Preserve curvearray(1 To UBound(curvearray) + 1)

Next looprun

Range("onepaste").Resize(UBound(arrayone)) = Application.Transpose(arrayone)
Range("twopaste").Resize(UBound(arraytwo)) = Application.Transpose(arraytwo)
Range("curvepast").Resize(UBound(curvearray)) = Application.Transpose(curvearray)

End Sub
```

Comment: Spelling!  `curvarray` vs `curvearray`.  (Use Option Explicit to help avoid these errors)

Comment: Thanks @chris neilsen.  I actually found that and fixed.  Think the other problem has to do with the sizing of the array.